odoo v17 render one2many field on crm kanban card
I have added a custom one2many field in crm.lead model:
class CrmLead(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'crm.lead'

    ​quote_ids = fields.One2many('insurance.quotes', 'crm_lead_id', string='Quotes')

related model code is:
class InsuranceQuotes(models.Model):

    _name = 'insurance.quotes'

    _description = 'Insurance Quotes'



    crm_lead_id = fields.Many2one('crm.lead', string='CRM Lead')

    broker_id = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Broker', domain="[('is_broker', '=', True)]", context={'default_is_broker': True})

My kanban vide code is:
<record id="view_crm_lead_kanban_inherit_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.inherit.custom</field>
    <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_bottom')]" position="after">
            <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right o_kanban_bottom_extra">
                <t t-set="record" t-value="record"/>
                <li t-foreach="record.quote_ids" t-as="quote">
                    <p t-esc="quote.partner_id.name"/>
                </li>
            </div>
        </xpath>
    </field>
</record>

I get following error when I open crm module:
UncaughtPromiseError > OwlError

Uncaught Promise > Invalid loop expression: "undefined" is not iterable

Can anyone help me with correct version odoo 17 syntax. TIA

You could try replacing de foreach loop with a field component and display the html outcome you want in a new computed field...
In your model add the new computed field
class CrmLead(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'crm.lead'
    quote_ids = fields.One2many('jca.owl.cart.insurance.quotes', 'crm_lead_id', string='Quotes')
    quote_ids_ul = fields.Html(string='Quotes li', compute='_compute_quote_li')

    @api.depends('quote_ids')
    def _compute_quote_li(self):
        ul=""
        for lead in self:
            for quote in lead.quote_ids:
                ul+= f"<li>{quote.broker_id.name}</li>"
            lead.quote_ids_ul=ul

Then in your xml view...
<record id="view_crm_lead_kanban_inherit_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">crm.lead.kanban.inherit.custom</field>
            <field name="model">crm.lead</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="crm.crm_case_kanban_view_leads"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//div[hasclass('o_kanban_record_bottom')]" position="after">
                    <div class="oe_kanban_bottom_right o_kanban_bottom_extra">
                        <field name="quote_ids_ul"/>

                        <!-- <t t-set="record" t-value="record"/> 
                        <li t-foreach="record.quote_ids" t-as="quote">
                            <p t-esc="quote.partner_id.name"/>
                        </li> -->
                    </div>
                </xpath>
            </field

You could also use Odoo widgets and avoid creating the computed field...
<field name="quote_ids" widget="many2many_tags"/>

